# How can I select one of multiple PostgreSQL in my CentOS server?

Tags: centos, postgresql

I had postgresql 8.4 in centos system.
Aadditionally I needed postgresql 9.3.
I want new version, But excute 8.4 version instead 9.3 version.

How can I change default version?

Comment: You realize that there may be more to do now than just changing to the new version.

Comment: A program run on only a new version psql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your package manager may provide several versions, for instance:

```
yum install postgresql-8.4
yum install postgresql-9.3
```

Try using the tab key after "postgresql" to autocomplete the package list or look at the yum doc.

Then they may be accessible form the service command:

```
service postgresql start 8.4
service postgresql stop 9.3
```